# what does all: function() do?

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I work with crossfilter and dc.js. I found in this forum the function to remove empty bins from a chart. But I don't understand the return statement:

```
all:function() {..}
```

What does it mean? Never saw this before.

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
return {
    all: function () {
        return source_group.all().filter(function (d) {                
            return d.key !== '';
        });
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Do you understand `return { all: 'hello' }`?  And then instead of `all` being a string, `all` is a function.

Comment: Simply means that the function `remove_empty_bins`, instead of returning a value, returns an `object`, one of whose properties, `all` is  also a `function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

`all` is the property name.

`function () { ... }` is the value (the result of evauating a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)).

Comment: that was easy. Thanks =)

Comment: Specifically in dc.js terms: it's creating an object with the same interface as a crossfilter group. Since dc.js only calls `group.all()`, this is "all" that is needed.